# rendering a partial with object in js.erb file

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

this is my index/post for rendering a comment

```
<% @posts = Post.where(user_id: current_user.all_user_ids).order("created_at desc") %>

<%@posts.each do |post| %>
  <div id="comment-action">
    <button id="<%= "#{post.id}" %>"> View comment</button>
    <%= link_to "View Comments", "#post_comments_#{post.id}" %>

    <section class="comments-section" id="post_comments_<%= post.id %>" >
      <br>
      <div id="comments">
        <%= render 'commenters/newsfeedcomment', obj: post  %>
      </div>

      <% if current_user == post.user %>
        <h6 align="right"><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(post) %></h6>
        <h6 align="right"><%= link_to 'Delete', { :id => post ,:controller => 'posts',:action => 'destroy'} %></h6>
      <% end %>
    </section>                    
  </div>    
<% end %>
```

now i past a object to my _newsfeedcomment which is obj: post

heres my newsfeedcomment

```
<% obj.commenters.each do |c| %>
  <li class = 'comments'>
    <br><%= image_tag c.user.profile.avatar.url, size:"50x50" %> 
    <a href="<%= "#{profile_path(c.user.profile)}" %>">
    <%= c.user.profile.firstname + " " + c.user.profile.lastname %></a> : <%=   c.comment %>
    <br><%= time_ago_in_words(c.created_at) %> ago
  </li>

  <% if current_user == c.user %>
    <%= link_to "Delete comment", [c.post, c], method: :delete %>
    <%= link_to "Edit comment", edit_post_commenter_path(c.post, c) %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

and i want to render my newsfeedcomment again for my ajax

```
$('#comments').append("<%= j render(:partial => 'commenters/nesfeedcomment', obj: post) %>");
```

and this is my error

> undefined local variable or method `post' for #<#:0x007f8660e313e8>

i guess rails cant read my object? is there any approach so i can finish my project please someone help me...

heres my controller

```
def create
@comment = @post.commenters.create(params[:commenter].permit(:comment))
@comment.user_id = current_user.id
@comment.save

if @comment.save
  respond_to do |format|
  format.html {redirect_to posts_path}
  format.js
  end
else
  redirect_to posts_path
end
```

end

Comment: what action do you call `$('#comments').append...`? Please show your controller.

Comment: thanks for the reply i edit my post

Comment: you need to use `@post` instead of `post`: `$('#comments').append("<%= j render(:partial => 'commenters/nesfeedcomment', obj: @post) %>");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i create another render file just like newsfeedcomment

commenters/commentlist.html.erb

```
    <li class = 'comments'>
<br><%= image_tag @comment.user.profile.avatar.url, size:"50x50" %> 
<a href="<%= "#{profile_path(@comment.user.profile)}" %>">
<%= @comment.user.profile.firstname + " " + @comment.user.profile.lastname %></a> : <%= @comment.comment %>

<br><%= time_ago_in_words(@comment.created_at) %> ago

<% if current_user == @comment.user %>
        <%= link_to "Delete comment", [@comment.post, @comment], method: :delete %>
        <%= link_to "Edit comment", edit_post_commenter_path(@comment.post, @comment) %>
    <% end %>
</li>
```

and this is my create.js.erb

```
var content = "<%= j render(:partial => 'commenters/commentlist', obj: @comment) %>";

var $post = $("#post_comments_<%= @comment.post_id %>");
var $last_comment = $post.find('#comments > li:last');

if ($last_comment.length > 0) {
$last_comment.after(content);
} else { 
var $comments = $post.find('#comments');
$comments.prepend(content)          
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`<%= render 'commenters/newsfeedcomment', obj: post  %>`

This code works in `index.html` because `post` is just the looped object from `@posts`

---

UPDATE:
Thanks for updating with your controller.
What you'll want to do is to provide a `.js` format response to your `comments_controller`'s `create` action.

This can be done by providing a rendered view as `app/views/comments/create.js.erb`

In the `create.js.erb`, just have:

`$('#comments').append("<%= j render(:partial => 'commenters/nesfeedcomment', obj: @post) %>");`

or

`$('#comments').append("<%= j render(:partial => 'commenters/nesfeedcomment', obj: @comment.post) %>");`

And that is it.

What you were missing is simply the definition of `post` in your block, because it was not assigned as a variable, and ruby is interpreting it as a call for some method `post` - hence your error message: `undefined local variable or method 'post'`.

Comment: it really confuse me can i define my post in js.erb?

Comment: thanks for sharing your knowledge but im working in the comment not in the post? it really confuse me T_T

Comment: @GeromeJohnPangan updated with a new understanding of your controller. I hope it addresses your concerns:

1. Why you are receiving the error and what it means
2. How to provide a js response using Rails views

Comment: > undefined local variable or method `obj' for #<#<Class:0x007fce73146880>:0x007fce8d7caa48>

Comment: thanks for the help cedric and it gives me a lot of idea